# IdentityServer4 Fedarated Gateway Resource Owner Setup

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, identityserver4

We are trying to split apart Authorization and Authentication into two separate services.  Both will use Identity Server 4.  We may someday add in additional external Authentication providers.  I believe Federated Gateway is the term (http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/federation_gateway.html?highlight=Federation)

My research so far indicates we are able to setup Authorization as External Providers and set [LocalLoginEnabled] to false. This works fine for web apps, since it redirects along the traditional flows.   Our requirement is to have both Web-based and client-apps (Windows and Mobile) calling our solution.  This would need Implicit or Resource Owner (password) flows.

Looking for guidance on the best way to set this up. I'm tempted to write a custom endpoint API to relay the authentication to authentication instance.

QUESTION:

How can I achieve "password flow" between two ID4 instances (Authorization + Authentication)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although my original answer worked, it was not the best way to accomplish my end result. Instead of creating a new endpoint, I am able to inject my own handling of password grants by extending the IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator.  I can then have a single endpoint for all authorization. This solution is more "natural" and falls inline with the intended architecture.

The IResourceOwnerValidator interface just implements one function...

*public Task ValidateAsync(ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context)*

A much more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

After much research and little guidance, I decided to take a leap and just created a new API Endpoint used only for Resource Owner / Password Grant Types. This API simply validates the necessary information was present grant-type, secret, user/pwd etc... and then relays it to the Authentication instance. There may be more "elegant" ways of doing this, but this one seems to be working.

Hope this might help someone.